# Passing the "resources" property value to multiResourceReader from previous step in spring batch

Tags: spring, resources, spring-batch

I need to read csv files from a folder and write to DB, also archive the files. Below is the job described in xml

```
<job id="importJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
          <step id="validateFileStep" >
            <tasklet ref="validateFileTasklet" />            
              <next on="*" to="importFileStep" />
              <next on="FAILED" to="archiveFileStep" />               
        </step>  
    <step id="importFileStep"  next="archiveFileStep">          
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="csvWriter"
                    commit-interval="1" >                   
                </chunk>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
        <step id="archiveFileStep">
            <tasklet ref="archiveFileTasklet" />
        </step>             
    </job>
```

multiResourceReader bean definition

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader"  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:data/*.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="csvReader" />
  </bean>
```

The code is working fine, but instead of providing the "resources" property value in xml, i need to get it from "validateFileStep" step, as the reader should read only those csv files which are formatted properly. I should pass the same to archiveFileStep also, so that name the files can be appended with completed or failed in the archive accordingly.

below is the reader bean def

```
    <!-- property to skip the headers, as no headers in CSV, value is 0 -->
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="0" />       
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                    <!-- Names of the CSV columns -->
                    <property name="names"
                        value="id,name,city" />
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="com.common.service.csvFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```